# RAID10 with 2 disks with far2 layout

Tags: mdadm, raid-10

RAID10 with 2 disks is reliable with **far2** layout? Will it provide fault tolerance in case of one hard disk failure?

Any advantage over plain RAID1?

Answer (score 0):

The big benefit of using raid10 is that it will be easier to expand the array later on by adding more drives.

With a two drive array, on either raid1 or raid10,far2, the array should stay online even though one drive fails.

ref https://serverfault.com/a/140506/127536

It looks like raid10 may have better performance for multithreaded work as well. Although this post is a bit old and newer kernels may do better at this.

ref https://blog.a2o.si/2014/09/07/linux-software-raid-why-you-should-always-use-raid-10-instead-of-raid-1/